# Generalization of Radon's theorem

Tags: gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, convexity, alexandrov-geometry

A Cat(0) metric space $(X,d)$ of constant and finite local dimension is approximately flat if there exists a dense subset $U\subset X$ such that every $x\in U$ has a flat neighborhood (i.e. isometric to the euclidean space).

I'm interested in a generalization of Radon's theorem (https://matthewhr.wordpress.com/2013/02/27/radons-theorem/) to approximately flat Cat(0) spaces. Do you know if there exists one?

Thank you.

Comment: What about trees, for instance a standard 3-valenced tree. Take two subset of N+1 elements, says two ball of radius $log _3 N$ with a huge distance.

Comment: @Thomas: I don't see how your counter-example would work. If one labels one vertex on each subset as red, and one vertex on each subset as blue, then the convex hull of red points intersects the convex hull of blue points along the path between the two subsets.

Comment: I think you would need at least some dimension constraint: a Cat(0) metric space can contain flat pieces of arbitrary large dimension.

Comment: @Benoît Kloeckner what do you mean? every point $x\in U$ has an open flat neighborhood so the dimension is the same as the one of $X$

Comment: @user00169: you did not precise what you meant by flat then, nor that $X$ had finite dimension. A Cat(0) space need not have constant local dimension.

Comment: sorry, I'll correct it. by flat I mean isometric to the euclidean space

Comment: You missed the point: do you mean isometric of Euclidean space of a fixed, given dimension, or arbitrary Euclidean space whose dimension can vary from point to point?

Comment: I mean Euclidean space of fixen, given dimension, I thought it was clear

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In dimension 1, Radon's theorem says that for any 3 points on the real line, one of them belongs to the segment between the two others. This becomes false if one replaces the real line by the tripod (the tree with 3 leaves), which is a 1-dimensional CAT(0) space. Indeed, none of the three leaf vertices of the tripod in on the segment between the two others.

So the most straightforward generalization fails. However if you are willing to increase the number of points in the set, then a generalization is possible. Moreover the local flatness in not needed.

Namely if $\dim X=n$ then $2n+2$ points is enough (I don't know if this bound is optimal). This follows from the case $r=2$ of Theorem 5.2 in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1011.1802), which asserts that, for any continuous map $f:\Delta^{2n+1}\to X$, where $\Delta^{2n+1}$ is the standard $(2n+1)$-dimensional simplex, there exists two disjoint faces of the simplex whose images do intersect. Here $X$ is any $n$-dimensional metric space, not necessarily CAT(0).

To derive the Radon-type theorem from this fact it suffices to construct, for a given $S\subset X$ with $|S|=2n+2$, a map $f:\Delta^{2n+1}\to X$ which maps the vertices of the simplex to points of $S$ and maps each face of the simplex to the convex hull of the images of its vertices. This is easy to do in CAT(0).